# Jquery Mobile pre-cache page

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile I have 2 pages, index.html and test.html. There is a `<p>` tag in the index page which has a class, so when the `<p>` tag is clicked on my javascript, it wants to load test.html.

But with jQuery Mobile when the index page loads the test page, it is not in the DOM. So in order to go to the test page and replace the contents of a div in test.html it must first be loaded into the DOM. So here is what I am doing:

When try2 is clicked, I do a load page to get it into the DOM, then I replace the div with the new html, and then I change to the page. The html of the div never changes.

```
$('.try2')
  .click(function(){
    $.mobile.loadPage( 'test.html', { showLoadMsg: false } );
    $('#mytest').html('i am here now').fadeIn('slow');
    $.mobile.changePage( "test.html", { transition: "slideup"} );
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-fetch the page by using the data-prefetch attribute on a link that points to the second page. Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Then bind to either the pageinit or pageshow event to update the div before the second page is transitioned into view.

Your current code won't work because the first two lines in your event handler are asynchronous, so to use them you would have to utilize the callback functions for the asynchronous functions.

**Update**

If you want to pre-cache a page but don't have a direct link to the page, you can always create a dummy link and hide it from view:

```
<a data-precache href="page2.html" style="display:none;"></a>
```

Comment: I have used the data-prefetch if I use a href. Which worked without binding to the pageinit. But on the same page it says that alternatively I can use the pageLoad instead of data-precache. I'll have to look father into the pageinit

Comment: ok look at it this way. index page is a login page. So when I click the login button it has to change the actual page to the Page1.html. Now in login there is no href to add the data-prefetch to. So I just dont understand how to change from on page to another and yet have it still be able to access all the js functions

Comment: That's what the `pageinit` event handler is for. No matter how the page enters the DOM, once jQuery Mobile initializes the page, you will get to run your code.